# How to prevent css columns from wrapping with Tailwindcss

Tags: css, tailwind-css

Using tailwindcss I have the following html

```
<ol class="relative columns-1 sm:columns-3">
   <li>
       <img src="https://placehold.co/400x300">id=voluptas minus a qui tempore
   </li>
   <li>...</li>
   ...
</ol>
```

The relevant Tailwind css for the **ol** is

```
.sm:columns-3 {
   columns: 3;
}
```

[image]

As you can see (red arrow) one cell is wrapped. The other part of that cell is at the bottom of the middle column. This is something I don't want, no wrapping. Is there some way this can be prevented or should I make sure that all cells have the same height?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To prevent CSS columns from wrapping in Tailwind CSS, you can use the break-inside property. Setting break-inside to avoid-column on the `<li>` elements will prevent them from being split across columns, you can try this logic:

```
<ol class="relative columns-1 sm:columns-3">
  <li class="break-inside-avoid-column">
    <img src="https://placehold.co/400x300">id=voluptas minus a qui tempore
  </li>
  <li class="break-inside-avoid-column">...</li>
  ...
</ol>
```

The break-inside-avoid-column utility class is provided by Tailwind CSS and sets the break-inside property to avoid-column. This ensures that each `<li>` element remains intact within its column without being split.

Comment: In my case this wouldn't work, however it *did* work when applying the class to the `<ul>` directly: `<ul class="break-inside-avoid-column"><li>foo</li><li>bar</li></ul>`

Comment: I used directly on `<div className="w-full shadow-lg rounded-md m-2 p-2 break-inside-avoid-column">` section instad `<ul...>` in my case and works perfectly